# How to extract an incomplete 7-Zip file?

Tags: 7-zip

I almost (98%) downloaded a `file.7z` which contains multiple files. The missing part is in the middle of `file.7z`.

So I only get 50% of all contained files when extracting with 7-Zip. How can I extract it as far as possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [WinRar](http://www.rarlabs.com/) and 7-zip to decompress the file and see which gets further. If the corruption is in the middle of the file it's not likely you'll get more than what you already have - you're probably far better off re-downloading the file.

Answer (score -1):

Start re-downloading the file in Firefox and when it completes just 1 or 2 MB, go to Task Manager and end the task `firefox.exe`, then copy your 99%  incompleted file in the currently downloading file and overwrite the same. Now start Firefox, and it will promt you for a restore session. Select retore previous session.

You will see within a minute your file completes.

Comment: Sounds pretty slick if that works.  Sounds like you should copy the 99% file before doing what you state.  (Also, a period after "restore session" would be more clear.)

Comment: this will only work if the server supports resuming of download