# Is there a way to download parts of the content of a zip file?

Tags: download, webserver, zip

If there is a big zip file uploaded on a server, and all you need is some of it's content, is there a way to open it, and choose what you want to download?

Comment: So the question is really generic, but usually not. With some compressed format you can be able to extract some of its content from the incomplete file `rar x --kb myincompletefile.rar`. For [`7zip` see even this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/391388/how-to-extract-a-incomplete-7zip-file). Which kind of server do you mean? Are you using `zip` just to say compressed or you refer strictly to `zip` files?

Comment: i am talking about a file puted online for download via http or ftp protocol or even a torrent, and  i refer  strictly to .zip file.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that your answer will be _No_. :-( But you can always start to download, try to fix/extract the partial part, and see if there is what you need... If you refer to distribution of software with unique zip file under ftp, some times they have the _"open"_ version too that you can explore as a normal path... I think to something like [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/) mirrors...

Comment: thank you very much for the infos, i wish i could set your comment as useful but i am level 1

Comment: I suspect such a thing would be possible, by downloading the header, and then using HTTP options related to resuming a partial download.  If you're a programmer, you may be able to get it to work.  However, I haven't heard of this done in practice.  Getting just part of a file is something that is commonly done with media (audio/video), and may use "streaming" technology (historically other protocols, or web browser add-ons like Flash; at the moment I'm not sure if HTML5 could do similar).  So, since I haven't heard of this actually being done in actual practice, I agree with the "no" answers.

Comment: I've subsequently found [ http://stackoverflow.com/a/15321699/4411648 ](Downloading just some data from zip file) which appears to discuss actually doing, in practice, what I was just theorizing in the first two sentences (of my above comment).

Comment: @TOOGAM, neat. I would not have expected there to be fuse filesystems over HTTP. very kewl. By doing it that way, the unzip command has full access to the whole file, for the purpose of decrypting, but only pulls down the necessary bits (like the aliases). i wonder how webserver support for HTTPFS is.

Comment: thanks for your replay. talking from programming viewpoint, it's an easy service to concept, i wonder why the storage websites didn't offer this option. it will save them bandwidth and save us time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a Python script `list_remote_zip.py` that can list files in a zip file that is accessible over HTTP:

```python
import urllib2, struct, sys

def open_remote_zip(url, offset=0):
 return urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, headers={'Range': 'bytes={}-'.format(offset)}))

offset = 0
zipfile = open_remote_zip(sys.argv[1])
header = zipfile.read(30)

while header[:4] == 'PK\x03\x04':
 compressed_len, uncompressed_len = struct.unpack('<II', header[18:26])
 filename_len, extra_len = struct.unpack('<HH', header[26:30])
 header_len = 30 + filename_len + extra_len
 total_len = header_len + compressed_len

 print('{}\n offset: {}\n length: {}\n  header: {}\n  payload: {}\n uncompressed length: {}'.format(zipfile.read(filename_len), offset, total_len, header_len, compressed_len, uncompressed_len))
 zipfile.close()

 offset += total_len
 zipfile = open_remote_zip(sys.argv[1], offset)
 header = zipfile.read(30)

zipfile.close()
```

It does not use the zip file's central directory, which is near the end of the file. Instead, it goes from the start and parses individual local headers and skips over the payload, hoping to land at another header. It sends a new request every time it needs to skip to an offset. This of course only works with servers that support the `Range` HTTP header.

It only needs to be passed the URL to the zip file as a command line argument. Example usage and output should look something like this:

```sh
$ python list_remote_zip.py http://dl.xonotic.org/xonotic-0.8.1.zip
Xonotic/Makefile
 offset: 0
 length: 1074
  header: 46
  payload: 1028
 uncompressed length: 5019
Xonotic/source/darkplaces/
 offset: 1074
 length: 56
  header: 56
  payload: 0
 uncompressed length: 0
Xonotic/source/darkplaces/bih.h
 offset: 1130
 length: 1166
  header: 61
  payload: 1105
 uncompressed length: 2508
Xonotic/source/darkplaces/portals.h
 offset: 2296
 length: 334
  header: 65
  payload: 269
 uncompressed length: 648
...
```

To download one of the files, I wrote an even uglier `get_file_from_remote_zip.sh` bash script around it that uses `wget`:

```sh
info=$(python list_remote_zip.py "$1" | grep -m 1 -A 5 "^$2\$" | tail -n +2)
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

wget --start-pos $(echo "$info" | grep offset | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*') -O - "$1" | head -c $(echo "$info" | grep -m 1 length | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*') >"$tmpfile"

printf '\x1f\x8b' # gzip magic
tail -c +9 <"$tmpfile" | head -c 1 # copy compression method
printf '\0\0\0\0\0\0\x03' # some flags and mtime
tail -c "+$(expr 1 + $(echo "$info" | grep header | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*'))" <"$tmpfile"
tail -c +15 <"$tmpfile" | head -c 4 # The CRCs seem to be compatible.
tail -c +23 <"$tmpfile" | head -c 4

rm "$tmpfile"
```

It takes 2 arguments. The first is the URL of the zip file and the second the file to be extracted. The to-be-extracted file's name has to be complete and exactly as it appears in the output of the previous `list_remote_zip.py` Python script, which it uses to get some information about the file. It then uses `wget` to download it at the right offset with the right length. It saves this zip "slice" to a temporary file, which is then used to output a `gzip`-formatted file, which can then be piped to and decompressed with `gzip`. The "slice" itself is not a valid zip file because it has no central directory at the end. It could be fixed with `zip`'s `-FF` option but I decided to instead change the headers a little and convert it to a gzip file. Both (PK)zip and gzip use the same [deflate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) compression algorithm and even the CRC-32 checksums seem to be compatible.

Here is an example of how to download a random file from Xonotic's archive available at http://dl.xonotic.org/xonotic-0.8.1.zip, decompress it and save it to a local file:

```
bash get_file_from_remote_zip.sh http://dl.xonotic.org/xonotic-0.8.1.zip Xonotic/source/darkplaces/mprogdefs.h | gzip -d >mprogdefs.h
```

Comment: By the way, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970989) helped.

Comment: The first block of code is a Python (2) script that I called `list_remote_zip.py`. So if you have Python installed, you can run it and pass it the URL to the zip file as a command line argument like so:

`python list_remote_zip.py http://dl.xonotic.org/xonotic-0.8.1.zip`

Comment: The second script is a Unix shell script, that should be runnable with bash and similar. I expanded the answer a little bit to hopefully make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Brilliant method! I will be testing this out for the purpose of optimizing the download of a subset of data from a much larger very large dataset (I only need like 3% of the actual data). Seriously, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Mount the remote ZIP file via an HTTP-backed virtual filesystem and then use the standard unzip command on it. This way the unzip utility's I/O calls are translated to HTTP range GETs, which means only the chunks of the ZIP file that you want get transferred over the network.

Here's an example for Linux using [HTTPFS](http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/), a very lightweight FUSE-based virtual filesystem. There are similar tools for Windows. Programming languages like Python and Java provide HTTP I/O as well, just combine them with their ZIP-reading logic appropriately.

**Get/build httpfs:**

```
$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/httpfs/files/httpfs/1.06.07.02
$ tar -xjf httpfs_1.06.07.10.tar.bz2
$ rm httpfs
$ ./make_httpfs
```

**Mount a remote ZIP file and extract one file from it:**

```
$ mkdir mount_pt
$ sudo ./httpfs http://example.com/zipfile.zip mount_pt
$ ls mount_pt
zipfile.zip
$ unzip -p mount_pt/zipfile.zip the_file_I_want.txt > the_file_I_want.txt
$ sudo umount mount_pt
```

(need for `sudo` may vary based on how FUSE is setup on your system)

Of course you can also use whatever other tools beside the command-line one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing a file server and have winrar (and probably other similar applications) installed, you can open the .zip and drag out the files you want.

If you are talking about a web server, I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the server supports resumed downloads it would in theory be possible to write a client that did this--grab a big enough block near the end to get the directory, then use that to figure out what you need to grab to actually get the data--simply start downloading at that position and stop when you have enough data.  It's been so long since I was poking around I don't recall if there's a means of finding the start of the directory other than brute force.

I've never heard of such a client and can't imagine why one would be developed--if it's data that reasonably would be downloaded in pieces then why is the webmaster storing it as one big zip file???

Comment: there is cases when you download big zip file and some files of it get corrupted, so if this solution exist it will ease my life to download only the corrupted files.

Comment: @habibhassani In other words, the fact that it's a zip file isn't really relevant, you just want to recover a damaged piece of a file.

Comment: exactly, this question is based on my experiace

Answer (score 0):

```
`import urllib.request as urllib2, struct, sys

def open_remote_zip(url, offset=0):
 return urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, headers={'Range': 'bytes={}-'.format(offset)}))

offset = 0
zipfile = open_remote_zip(sys.argv[1])
header = zipfile.read(30)

while header[:4] == b'PK\x03\x04':
 print("hello")
 compressed_len, uncompressed_len = struct.unpack('<II', header[18:26])
 filename_len, extra_len = struct.unpack('<HH', header[26:30])
 header_len = 30 + filename_len + extra_len
 total_len = header_len + compressed_len

 print('{}\n offset: {}\n length: {}\n  header: {}\n  payload: {}\n uncompressed length: {}'.format(zipfile.read(filename_len), offset, total_len, header_len, compressed_len, uncompressed_len))
 zipfile.close()

 offset += total_len
 zipfile = open_remote_zip(sys.argv[1], offset)
 header = zipfile.read(30)

zipfile.close()`
```

Comment: Used and tested in Python3 - Notice b flag in the while conditiona loop to treat as binary

Comment: Why comment under your answer? It seems like your comment should be edited into your answer to make it better. However, please note that your answer DOES need more information, such as how to use it. Use the EDIT button to do all that and make your good answer better.